# Disabling PowerBI Tab within Microsoft Teams

Tags: office365, powerbi, microsoft-teams

I understand that it is possible to disable First Party and Third Party apps within Microsoft Teams:

**Microsoft 365 Admin Center > Settings> Services & Add-Ins > Microsoft Teams > Tenant-wide Settings > Apps**

Since PowerBI requires additional licensing (E5 or PowerBI Pro), I would like to disable the option to add this as a tab within Microsoft Teams.

Is this possible through the admin center or PowerShell?

[Add PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRFE3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Power Bi is one of the default tabs on the team and cannot be disabled.
Currently when users are signed in to MS Teams and do not have a PowerBI license the New 
tab still shows PowerBI, Although they can't actually add tabs.